# Image Upload / Laravel stores image as a .tmp and not .img file

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, frameworks

I created a Forum which should upload an image.

In my form i`ve

```
{{ Form::file('image') }}
```

This is a part of my controller:

```
public function store()
{
    $input = Input::all();

    $v = Validator::make($input, Post::$rules);

    if ($v->passes()) {

        $post = new Post;
        $post->title = Input::get('title');
        $post->body = Input::get('body');

        $post->image = Input::file('image'); // your file upload input field in the form should be named 'file'

        $destinationPath = 'uploads/'.str_random(8);
        $filename = $post->image->getClientOriginalName();
        $extension =$post->image->getClientOriginalExtension(); //if you need extension of the file
        $uploadSuccess = Input::file('image')->move($destinationPath, $filename);


        $post->m_keyw = Input::get('m_keyw');
        $post->m_desc = Input::get('m_desc');
        $post->slug = Str::slug(Input::get('title'));
        $post->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $post->save();

        return Redirect::route('posts.index');
    }

    return Redirect::back()->withErrors($v);
}
```

But laravel stores the image as a .tmp file in my database.

The path in my database is then "/uploads/xxxxx.tmp"

Why does laravel stores the image as .tmp and not as .img ?

What do i wrong and why does laravel stores the image as a .tmp file ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this line

```
$post->image = Input::file('image');
```

You assign the .temp image file to your model instance and that's what is stored in the database.

You can do it this way.

```
$post = new Post;

$post->title = Input::get('title');

$post->body = Input::get('body');

$file = Input::file('image');

$filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();

$destinationPath = 'uploads/'.str_random(8);

// This will store only the filename. Update with full path if you like

$post->image = $filename; 

$uploadSuccess = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by deleting the 'image' column in my $fillable variable. In Model Post.php

```
protected $table = "posts";

protected $fillable = [
    'title',
    'image', //delete if exists
    'content'
];
```

Answer (score -1):

`.tmp` file is the file which you select from your local computer. So you need to assign correct path to your model to store it with correct URL.